# updation in database related to a web service

Tags: iphone

we can fetch data from xml file through a link but can we update that xml file data through link.. and make changes in database related to it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a web database, then you need to send a [web request](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest). Package your data as a [json object](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) or something and have the web server handle it.

If you mean on the iPhone, you need to read up on SQLite.